# original picture within cropped picture?

Tags: c#, image, crop, picturebox

i'm currently trying to crop an image, then send the crop image from the preview to a pictureBox but the pictureBox is showing both the original and the cropped combine.
im learning cropping from the Microsoft sample "CSWinFormCropImage". [MS linke](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinFormCropImage-d4beb1fa)
[image: MS link]

here is the code i have been editing.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Boolean bHaveMouse;
    Point ptOriginal = new Point();
    Point ptLast = new Point();
    Rectangle rectCropArea;
    Image srcImage = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bHaveMouse = false;
    }

    private void BtnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TargetPicBox.Size = new Size(rectCropArea.Width, rectCropArea.Height);
        TargetPicBox.Refresh();
        //Prepare a new Bitmap on which the cropped image will be drawn
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(SrcPicBox.Image, SrcPicBox.Width, SrcPicBox.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(sourceBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, TargetPicBox.Width, TargetPicBox.Height), 
            rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        }
        TargetPicBox.Image = sourceBitmap;


    }
```

i have not edited any of the other code that controls the cropping tool. cause i think my issue is with BtnCrop_click and targetPicBox.Image = sourceBitmap.

Comment: _Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(SrcPicBox.Image, SrcPicBox.Width, SrcPicBox.Height);_ makes the sourceBitmap in the old larger size. Shouldn't you amke the `new Bitmap(SrcPicBox.Image, TargetPicBox.Width, TargetPicBox.Height);`. Actually you may want to use CLientSize. You are not perhaps using the BackgroundImage?

Comment: You have added a PictureBox and a Button. You don't show us the Button's code, though. Tell  us the names of all controls and show us their code!

Comment: TaW. the code for the button is "pictureBox1.Image = tarGetPicBox.Image;"